# WPF Toolkit DataGrid: Sorting with Null Values

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I want to sort a WPF-Toolkit DataGrid on a column which is bound like this:

```
<toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumn" Binding="{Binding AnObject.AProperty}" />
</toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Now when AnObject is null, an ArgumentException with the Message *"At least one object must implement IComparable"* will be thrown.

What's the best way to work around this limitation? I don't really want to change the domain model to return a NullObject-Pattern.

Using Convertors in combination with a binding directly to AnObject could turn out to be quite cumbersome, since I have many of those columns and more than one DataGrid.

Should I write a custom ViewModel foreach DataGrid and use a Converter on the ItemsSource Property?

I appreciate every suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best solution here:

[WPF Datagrid sort on column with null elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645823/wpf-datagrid-sort-on-column-with-null-elements)

Implemented a custom sorter for my DataGrids which convers null values.

Comment: Umm... This link links back to the same question!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a different strategy: create a ViewModel for AnObject with a property that exposes AProperty and use it on all DataGrids. The VM should be capable of sending out the appropriate values on AProperty when AnObject is null.

Comment: But then I'd have to convert the DataGrid's ItemSource (a list of Domain-Entities) to a Model containing the ViewModel for AnObject. Many thanks for your opinion, though.